# How do I rewrite filename using RewriteEngine of apache to include get data?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

And the prize for the worst title goes to me :)

Hi,

I have a peculiar case when I need url:

```
sample.mp4
```

to be internally rewritten as:

```
sample.mp4?start=400&end=500
```

So that every request to that file will give me only preview of the video.

Is this doable with apache RewriteEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, this will work for sample.mp4?start=400&end=500 as well as with any generic values for start and end

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sample\.mp4$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=(.*)&end=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/sample.mp4? [R=301,L]
```